# How to find go package version?

Tags: go, package, version

I am not using go modules. Have a bunch of packages present in my company's toolchain (i.e. I didn't install the packages and thus can't check my bash history for package version).
So the packages are present in `$TOOLCHAIN_PATH/go/src`. Is there any way I can find the version of a particular package.
If it helps, I want to find out the package version of `crypto/tls`.

Comment: The package `crypto/tls` is part of the Go installation.  Run `go version` to find the version of Go.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not using go modules

So you are doing it wrong. It's 2021, you must use modules. Use modules.

> I want to find out the package version of crypto/tls

This is a package of the stdlib which is shipped with your compiler and it is "unversioned" as a *package*. Run `go version` to see the version of your compiler/stdlib combination as a whole.